# Accessing web app running in a VM from host using SSH tunnel

Tags: 20.04, ssh, windows-10, vmware

Perhaps there is a better way of doing this, but I'm trying to access the web app running in the VM (VMware Player 16) from the host's Chrome browser.

- The host is Windows 10 and the VM is Ubuntu.
- I have a web app running in the Ubuntu VM at `192.168.39.113:80` (`minikube` VM inside of `kvm2`).
- The VM is using a bridged connection and has an IP of `10.0.0.205`.
- I installed SSH on the Ubuntu VM with `sudo apt install openssh-server`.
- I can SSH into the VM from the host now.
- I'm trying to create a tunnel with `ssh -L 8080:192.168.39.113:80 username@10.0.0.205`, but I'm still unable to to connect to the web app from the host's browser when I go to `10.0.0.205:8080`.
- I did enable `AllowTcpForwarding yes` followed by `sudo service sshd restart`, which still I'm not able to connect to the web app from the hosts browser when I go to `10.0.0.205:8080`.

Suggestions for how to resolve this?

Comment: When SSH'd into the VM, are you actually able to access something at `192.168.39.113:80`? If this is minikube, meaning you're using Kubernetes, shouldn't there be a service and ingress involved?

Comment: Yes there is an `ingress-nginx` that should be taking the `192.168.39.113:80` and routing it to the correct services. I'm able to send `kubectl` commands to the cluster from SSH, but not able to access `192.168.39.113`.

Comment: Then you should probably run `minikube service ...` to get a host/port accessible from the VM, and then forward that over SSH.

Comment: Right, the `minikube ip` is the `19.168.39.113`, so that is what I should be using, correct?

Comment: See step 4 in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#deploy-a-hello-world-app or step 3 in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left off the local IP address in your command, which implies either use "127.0.0.1:8080" or "localhost:8080" in your local browser... or, alternatively, add the local IP that you want to use in the SSH command.

I tested with `zim` and started its web browser in one of my Virtualbox VMs..

If I wanted to use any **other** "local host" ip like **127.10.10.1** in my browswer, I had to specifically designate it: `ssh -L 127.10.10.1:5151:192.168.100.100:6968 grinch@192.168.100.100`

This worked using either the remote ssh server or the local ssh server **(grinch@192.168.100.5)** and I did not have to change sshd_config as AllowTcpForwarding is set to yes by default.

The only real blocker was attempting to use a specific IP address in the browser without designating one in the ssh -L command.